# how to mute and un mute microphone in video recording in android?

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I'm recording a video with the camera, using the `MediaRecorder` class and I want while recording, to be able to `mute/unmute` microphone at some point.

How's that possible?

I'm setting the audio source at start

```
mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
```

Comment: use AudioManager instance like audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);